# Having issues to plot with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Could someone help me with a hint to plot these vervet monkey behavioral data? Here are the codes and my expectation.

I want to plot vervet monkeys and I got stuck.

```
males<-c(21,50,25,12,15,1,5)
females<-c(20,30,22,12,16,46,8)
activities<- c("playing", "grooming", "dancing", "feeding", "mating", "fighting", "eating")

Vervet<-data.frame(activities,females, males)

Vervet |> 
  pivot_longer(females:males, values_to = "Count", names_to = "Gender") |>
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x= activities , y= Count, fill= Gender))+ geom_col(position = "dodge")+
  scale_fill_continuous()+
  coord_flip()+
theme_bw()+
theme(panel.grid = element_blank())
```

And here are my expectation graph.

[image]

Comment: You can click on the above message " enter image description here" to have information on expected grapg. Thank you

Comment: Remove `scale_fill_continuous()+` (and optionally remove `coord_flip()+`) and you'll end up with a plot that looks almost identical to your expected graph.

Comment: and then `... + scale_fill_discrete(name = NULL)` to remove the legend name. Optionally `+ labs(x = "Activities")` (or up-case the original frame's column name). You can include `theme(..., axis.line = element_line(arrow=arrow(type="closed")), panel.border = element_blank())` to change the axis lines. Similarly you can change the `axis.ticks` as desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created more or less what you were looking for. The colors don't match exactly, but you can change that for sure. Maybe also reconsider having the axis labels in place.

```r
library(tidyverse)
males<-c(21,50,25,12,15,1,5)
females<-c(20,30,22,12,16,46,8)
activities<- c("playing", "grooming", "dancing", "feeding", "mating", "fighting", "eating")

Vervet<-data.frame(activities,females, males)

Vervet %>%
  pivot_longer(females:males, values_to = "Count", names_to = "Gender") |>
  ggplot(aes(x= activities , y= Count, fill= Gender, color= Gender))+ 
  geom_col(position = "dodge")+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("lightblue", "khaki"))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = alpha(c("lightblue", "khaki"), 0.5))+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.line =  element_line(arrow=arrow(type = "closed", 
                                              length= unit(unit(3, "mm")))))+
  labs(x= "Activities")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

just adapted the colors. the theme part is from @Nick Glättli:

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

Vervet |> 
  pivot_longer(-activities, values_to = "Count", names_to = "Gender") |>
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x= activities , y= Count, fill= Gender, color=Gender))+
  geom_col(position = "dodge")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#d9e8fb", "#ffe6cd"))+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#899cba", "#c49f49"))+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.line =  element_line(arrow=arrow(type = "closed", 
                                              length= unit(unit(3, "mm")))))
```

[image]